# jquery themeroller - out of the box example does not grey the modal dialog backgound

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the latest jquery themeroller - so far looks great.

Except the modal dialog example and out of the box functionality of modal dialog boxes does not display the transparent curtain behind the current dialog box.

Anyone know how to enable this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the modal property to true in the dialog initialization

```
$(selector).dialog({modal:true});
```

Comment: Hi stephen776 sorry for the slow reply I've been on a quick hol. I'm using the following code  $('#sessionTimedOut').dialog({ modal:true, title: 'Session Timed out', draggable:false, resizable: false, open: function(event, ui) { } });   it works fine with the jquery defaults but there is no semi-transparent curtain behind the dialog box when I adopt the themeroller.

Comment: sounds like a css issue. Make sure the new themeroller css file is referenced correctly....Are the other styles working(other than the modal)?

Comment: Rolled another themeroller 1.8.9 and it worked sweetly. Thanks for the support stephen I thought I weas going crazy.